# iOS Google map - How to know when user begins or stop drag map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm developing with `Google map SDK 6.1` .I want to know when user begin drag or stop drag the map, I just found 2 delegate function : `didChangeCameraPosition` and `idleAtCameraPosition`. Is there a way to catch when user begin or stop drag the map?

Answer (score 36):

To detect if the user dragged the map I think it's better to use this delegate method

**Obj-C**

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture
```

**Swift**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool)
```

and check whether `gesture` argument is `true` or not.

---

The `didChangeCameraPosition` is called, as mentioned, many times but since it's also called by both setting the map center from code and as a result of a gesture you can't really see the difference in that method alone.

Comment: exactly what I've been looking for :) ...did not notice that the gesture param is bool when I was looking at documentation

Comment: this should be marked as accepted, because gesture is true only when user drags the map to change camera otherwise if the camera is changed explicitly by programming gesture variable is false.

Comment: the problem here is that zoom gesture also trigger this method with gesture=YES

Comment: I guess you can argue a zoom operation when you use two fingers on the map is a dragging operation too it's not triggered with `gesture=YES` when you programmatically call the zoom methods

Comment: Thank you got I solution. @Saifee

Comment: Thanks a lot! It saved my day!

Comment: Outstanding. I had so many other fiddly solutions to this problem, never realising the answer was just in front of me. Gesture bool thanks so much

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4:**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    if (gesture){
        print("dragged")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#aabd01d59d7680799a0c24d3c8b5e4622) :

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

Called when the map becomes idle, **after any outstanding gestures** or animations have completed (or after the camera has been explicitly set).

So with this delegate you can capture when the user stopped dragging the mapView.

To get notified when the user did start dragging, just use the other delegate you have pointed out:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

Called repeatedly during any animations **or gestures on the map** (or once, if the camera is explicitly set).

This may not be called for all intermediate camera positions. It is always called for the final position of an animation or gesture.

I'm not sure what is confusing you.

Comment: I have same problem as tequilar Tomsk asked, but your answer is what we can know from google sdk library class files, you just copied it from it and pasted here. What we want is some another approach from this.

Answer (score 1):

Beware idleAtCameraPosition is when map stops moving not when you lift your finger.

I had to subclass GSMapView and add PanGestureRecognizer >> State ENDED to get when finger lifted.

https://github.com/clearbrian/GoogleMapiOS_TapEndedGesture

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.1**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool)
```

This method only calls at the start of map view dragging, so it will not help to get the new coordinate.

By analysis on google api and other method, I did not get the proper one. The best and sweet answer for this question is by using pan gesture.

add the pan gesture to the mapView as

```
self.mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self. panHandler(_:)))
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Implementation of pan gesture method as

```
@objc private func panHandler(_ pan : UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if pan.state == .ended{
            let mapSize = self.mapView.frame.size
            let point = CGPoint(x: mapSize.width/2, y: mapSize.height/2)
            let newCoordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
            print(newCoordinate)
             //do task here
        }
}
```